# location service to send weather alert notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, weather-api

I have a client that wants an app that will detect the persons location and if a weather warning or alert happens send them a notification letting them know to check the warning.  I don't think the alert would have to have specifics because i will have all that information in the app.  It just needs to alert them to open the app and view details of warning or somthing to that nature.  Not sure where to start on something like this.  I have been looking at some weather api's that i could use for the forcasting and was planning on using a webview for radar services but not sure what i can use for the warning system.  If anyone has any ideas on where i can go with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: to clarify my question is how do I have the app check for weather warnings and if one is present in the user's area send a notification to alert them to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very broad, however here's a general approach.

Create a background service to:

- Track the user's location with GPS and / or Network locations
- Query [NOAA](http://alerts.weather.gov/) (or similar) for any alerts in the user's area
- If any are found, launch your Notification linked with your app to displays details, radar images, etc

Comment: this sounds like the approach that i think i wanna go in, do you know of any tutorials that might aid me in doing something like this

Comment: I don't know of any all encompassing tutorial, searching for individual tutorials is easy enough and the NOAA link above describes how to access their data. If you have a specific question does hesitate to ask a new question with relevant code and any logcat errors.

Comment: @Sam, Would JobScheduler better alternative then Background service for this kind of tasks?